# Passing image using SDWebImage from tableviewcontroller to detailview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage to pass an image located in my TableViewCell to a UIImageView in my Detail View Controller. For some reason, this line in my DetailViewController is throwing me the error: "No visible @interface for NSDictionary declares the selector sd_setImageWithURL". I've added the appropriate "UIImageView+WebCache.h" to both my TableViewController and the DetailViewController, so I'm not sure why this is happening; help!

**TableViewController.m**

```
FullArticleViewController *detailViewController = [[FullArticleViewController alloc]
                                                                initWithNibName:@"FullArticleViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.title = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];
detailViewController.articleDetail = [Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[detailViewController.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellImageLink]];
NSLog(@"cellImageLink is %@", cellImageLink);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UILabel *firstnameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *bodyLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *featureImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *articleDetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *featureImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellImageLink;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
featureImage.image = [UIImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellImageLink]];
NSLog(@"cellImageLink is %@", cellImageLink);
```

Comment: I think we need more context to help.  What type is `articleDetail` in  your `DetailViewController`?  It seems like a case of something being accessed as `id` and needing to be cast appropriately before use.

Comment: Hi @mckeejm, articleDetail is type NSDictionary. See edits above (I've changed articleDetail to UIImageView, but that didn't work either). I've posted the DetailViewController.h file.

Comment: it looked like you were calling `sd_setImageWithURL` on `articleDetail` which would definitely produce the error you mention.  I don't see that code in the updated OP however.

Comment: is this a compile time error or run-time error?

Comment: @mckeejm A compile time error; the app won't even run with this error. When I use UIImageView instead of articleDetail in that line of code, the error I get is, "No known class method for selector sd_setImageWithURL".

Comment: are you importing it like so `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not importing `SDWebImage` correctly. See the [example usage from the SDWebImage demos](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/Examples/SDWebImage%20Demo/DetailViewController.m)